# Запрос update через ORM и его результат

Tags: php, mysql, orm, idiorm

Работаю с кохана

Есть запрос,следующего вида

```
$sql = "update profiles set 
                ".$update_str." 
                where id = '".$profile_id."' and profiles.client_id=".$this - > client['id'];
$update_profile = ORM::for_table('profile') - > raw_query($sql);
```

Чему в итоге будет равно $update_profile?
И что нужно чтобы понять что все прошло хорошо?сравнить последнюю переменную с 1?а если запрос заменил в одной строке не все поля что ему сунули?

---

Ребят,вы случаем не слепые? Написано же ORM и результаты,за каким вы мне суете DB??

Comment: Это не kohana а idiorm

Comment: мб,но в некоторых исходниках проекта встречается в начале Kohana

Answer (score 1):

Функция `raw_query` относится к idiorm, а не к kohana, она возвращает `$this`, т.е. объект ORM.

В idiorm raw-запросы пишутся так:

```
ORM::raw_execute("update profiles set 
                    ".$update_str." 
                    where id = '".$profile_id."' and profiles.client_id=".$this->client['id']);
```

В Kohana это делается так:

```
DB::query(Database::UPDATE, "update profiles set 
                ".$update_str." 
                where id = '".$profile_id."' and profiles.client_id=".$this - > client['id'])->execute();
```

Функция `execute()` возвращает количество обновленных строк в таблице.

Но безопаснее и красивее пользоваться query builder-ом (построителем запросов):

```
DB::update('profiles')
            ->set(array('column' => 'value','column2' => 'value2'))
            ->where('id', '=', $profile_id)
            ->where('profiles.client_id', '=', $this->client['id'])
            ->execute();
```

Comment: без DB,только ORM)))

Comment: `raw_query()` и ORM в целом не предназначены для выполнения произвольных UPDATE запросов

Comment: @DarkVss Я вам уже ответил, что она возвращает `$this` - экземпляр класса ORM.

Comment: и?как по этому $this узнать статус?вы если отвечаете то отвечайте,пожалуйста,полностью.а не на часть.иначе смысл вашего ответа теряется в бессмысленности бытия.

Comment: А никак не узнать, потому что ORM для этого не предназначено, что я и пытаюсь до вас донести.
Есть еще функция `ORM::raw_execute()`, она возвращает `true` в случае успеха и `false` в случае ошибки.

Comment: а вот сразу об этом сказать нельзя было?

Comment: @DarkVss, http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/709/%D0%A7%D1%82%D0%BE-%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D0%9E%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BA%D0%B0-x-y-%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8-xy-problem

Comment: @Nofate ,да вы что все читать не умеете??? "И что нужно чтобы понять что все прошло хорошо?"-что в этом предложении не ясного?